# Use heading as column

Tags: excel, ssis

I have a spreadsheet set out similar to below:

```
Weekly Report | 25/06/2012

-------------------------------
Name          | Course        |
-------------------------------
Peter         | Maths         |
-------------------------------
John          | English       |
-------------------------------
James         | History       |
-------------------------------
```

Each week a new report is sent with sometimes different and sometimes the same people on different courses.  I want to use SSIS to create an extra column to show the date which is usually in cell b3 of the spreadsheet.

So the final thing would look like

```
Weekly Report | 25/06/2012

--------------------------------------------
Name          | Course        |   Date     |
--------------------------------------------
Peter         | Maths         | 25/06/2012 |
--------------------------------------------
John          | English       | 25/06/2012 |
-------------------------------------------- 
James         | History       | 25/06/2012 |
-------------------------------------------
```

Hopefully explained myself there.  I am rather new to SSIS so don't know if it's really obvious or something more difficult.

Comment: I don't understand your question, but SSIS is not a reporting tool so perhaps you're using the wrong approach here. Are you actually moving data between SQL Server and Excel, or are you just trying to format an Excel sheet? And where does the extra date data come from? You said it's in B3, but it looks like the word "Maths" (or perhaps "English") is in that cell?

Comment: Hi sorry for being vague. The idea is that I will receive 1 spreadsheet each week and will use SSIS to import them into MySQL. I want the date at the top of the spreadsheet to go next to each row of data for tht week so when more spreadsheets are added to the table I an tell which are from each week

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for clarifying your question. You have two steps: extracting the date and turning it into a column. I would probably use an Execute SQL task to [query the Excel sheet](http://sqlserversolutions.blogspot.com/2009/02/selecting-excel-range-in-ssis.html) and map the date to a package variable. Then you can use that variable in a [Derived Column transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141069.aspx) to add it to the data set being processed.

Finally, you might want to consider not using SSIS at all. If your source is Excel and your destination is MySQL, then using SSIS means you also need SQL Server. So depending on your environment writing your own script or program might be simpler.